# Outlook 365 - unable to cancel meeting that contains delete distribution list as attendee

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I'm trying to cancel a meeting and am receiving the error "an internal support function returned an error". The meeting has a deleted distribution list as an optional attendee, which I am confident is the root cause.

My question is - how can I work around or this? I have tried expanding the distribution list but as it's delete, this doesn't work. The only workaround to date is to email all attendees asking them to decline/delete the meeting, however, I'm sure there must be a better way to resolve this.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: In my opinion, due to we couldn't find the correct recipient, it's normal that we couldn't cancel a meeting with an invalid DL. As a workaround, based on my experience, if your list is also a Microsoft 365 group, we could try to recover it in exchange admin center within 30 days.

Comment: Hi @Jade - the main issue is that this is not a distribution list that I own or deleted. The original meeting which I set up was forwarded to a distribution list which now no longer exists.

Comment: I know it, I have also deleted a group accidently, which cause I couldn't send message or cancel meeting to them, and then I tried to restore it in admin center, everything is back.